# Java: modules are not supported in -source 8 in NetBeans and jdk_1.8

Tags: java, spring, maven, facebook-graph-api, netbeans

I open RestFB example from https://github.com/restfb/restfb-examples that is  Facebook Graph API client written in Java, but i can not run it in NetBeanse or inteliJ.

In netbeans in madule.info.java file, the first line where probably is definition of modules and shown as below:

```
module com.restfb.example {
  // Java FX modules
  requires javafx.web;
  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.fxml;
  // logging modules
  requires java.logging;
  requires jul.to.slf4j;
  // other modules
  requires restfb;
    requires jfxrt;
  requires rt;

  exports com.restfb.example;
}
```

I have an error look likes syntax errors shown on IDE as below:

> mudule are not supported in -source 8 in
> (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)

I open project in NetBeans IDE 12 and test with jdk1.8, 1.11, 1.15 but i have same result.

I test with InteliJ IDEA, there is no error before compile time but there are some error in output

thsnks

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you switched between the different versions of Java in NetBeans wen compiling your code? So, in your Project Properties > Build > Compile settings, which version of Java did you specify? (Also, are you really seeing "mudule" in the message, or did you mean "module"?)

Comment: I change Java version in Project Properties > Build > Compile settings, jdk_1.8, jdk_11_0_8, jdk_15_0_3. and this is "modules"

Comment: The Java Module System (JMS) was not implemented until Java 9, and the error message you are getting explicitly states that you cannot use  `-source 8`, presumably because module definitions are meaningless in Java 8. Are you assuming that module definitions should simply be ignored when using `-source 8`? That might seem a reasonable approach, but the precision of the error message shows that is clearly not the case. Or am I completely misunderstanding your concern?

Comment: With regard to using Intellij IDEA instead of NetBeans, [note this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003431700-Support-for-excluding-module-info-java-language-level-8-): _"when the project is configured to use JDK 8 (and 8 language level) it looks at module-info.java and adds --module-path to compiler command line"_. Perhaps NetBeans is doing something similar? You can check in the Output window.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on your `Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Source/Binary Format` set to something greater than 8.

Java modules were introduced in Java 9.